# Is double grouping possible with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Given `Row` type

```cs
public record Row(bool? Left, string OperatorName, bool? Right, bool? Result);
```

and a list of `Row`s.

This list is generated by a list of boolean operators (2 examples shown below) that I can omit the details for the sake of simplicity.

```cs
bool? xor(bool? x, bool? y) => x ^ y;
bool? xor_(bool? x, bool? y) => (!x & y) | (x & !y);
```

```cs
IEnumerable<Row> rows =
[
    new Row(null, "_or_", null, null),
    new Row(null, "_or_", true, true),
    new Row(null, "_or_", false, null),
    new Row(true, "_or_", true, true),
    new Row(true, "_or_", false, true),
    new Row(false, "_or_", false, false),

    new Row(null, "and", null, null),
    new Row(null, "and", true, null),
    new Row(null, "and", false, false),
    new Row(true, "and", true, true),
    new Row(true, "and", false, false),
    new Row(false, "and", false, false),

    new Row(null, "or", null, null),
    new Row(null, "or", true, true),
    new Row(null, "or", false, null),
    new Row(true, "or", true, true),
    new Row(true, "or", false, true),
    new Row(false, "or", false, false),

    new Row(null, "or_", null, null),
    new Row(null, "or_", true, true),
    new Row(null, "or_", false, null),
    new Row(true, "or_", true, true),
    new Row(true, "or_", false, true),
    new Row(false, "or_", false, false),

    new Row(null, "xor", null, null),
    new Row(null, "xor", true, null),
    new Row(null, "xor", false, null),
    new Row(true, "xor", true, false),
    new Row(true, "xor", false, true),
    new Row(false, "xor", false, false),

    new Row(null, "xor_", null, null),
    new Row(null, "xor_", true, null),
    new Row(null, "xor_", false, null),
    new Row(true, "xor_", true, false),
    new Row(true, "xor_", false, true),
    new Row(false, "xor_", false, false)
];
```

#### Objective

How to use Linq and `rows` to produce the following output on the console?

```
Group 1:
xor
xor_
Group 2:
and
Group 3:
_or_
or
or_
```

#### My idea

First group by `OperatorName`, so we have 6 groups

```cs
[
    new Row(null, "_or_", null, null),
    new Row(null, "_or_", true, true),
    new Row(null, "_or_", false, null),
    new Row(true, "_or_", true, true),
    new Row(true, "_or_", false, true),
    new Row(false, "_or_", false, false),
]
```

```cs
[
    new Row(null, "and", null, null),
    new Row(null, "and", true, null),
    new Row(null, "and", false, false),
    new Row(true, "and", true, true),
    new Row(true, "and", false, false),
    new Row(false, "and", false, false)   
]
```

```cs
[
    new Row(null, "or", null, null),
    new Row(null, "or", true, true),
    new Row(null, "or", false, null),
    new Row(true, "or", true, true),
    new Row(true, "or", false, true),
    new Row(false, "or", false, false)
]
```

```cs
[
    new Row(null, "or_", null, null),
    new Row(null, "or_", true, true),
    new Row(null, "or_", false, null),
    new Row(true, "or_", true, true),
    new Row(true, "or_", false, true),
    new Row(false, "or_", false, false),
]
```

```cs
[
    new Row(null, "xor", null, null),
    new Row(null, "xor", true, null),
    new Row(null, "xor", false, null),
    new Row(true, "xor", true, false),
    new Row(true, "xor", false, true),
    new Row(false, "xor", false, false)
]
```

```cs
[
    new Row(null, "xor_", null, null),
    new Row(null, "xor_", true, null),
    new Row(null, "xor_", false, null),
    new Row(true, "xor_", true, false),
    new Row(true, "xor_", false, true),
    new Row(false, "xor_", false, false)
]
```

Because `xor_` and `xor` are identical truth tables (because `(!x & y) | (x & !y)` and `x ^ y` are tautologies), then they must be in the same group. The second grouping is my problem. How to get the following output on the console?

```
Group 1:
xor
xor_
Group 2:
and
Group 3:
_or_
or
or_
```

### Last edit

For those who are confused in understanding the problem, now I illustrate with a much simpler one.

I have a list of `functions` and

```cs
(string name, Func<int,int> func) [] functions = new []
{
   ("a", x => 3*x + 1),
   ("b", x => 2*x + x + 1),
   ("c", x => x*x - x*x + 3*x +1),
   ("d", x => x*x),
   ("e", x => x*x + 1 -1),
   ("f", x => 2*(x+1) + x -1)
};
```

a list of `inputs`

```cs
int[] inputs = [0,1,2];
```

A list `rows` is generated by applying `inputs` to each function in `functions`. For simulation purposes,  `rows` is hard coded as follows.

```cs
(int x, string funcName, int y)[] rows =
[
   (0, "a", 1),
   (1, "a", 4),
   (2, "a", 7),

   (0, "b", 1),
   (1, "b", 4),
   (2, "b", 7),

   (0, "c", 1),
   (1, "c", 4),
   (2, "c", 7),

   (0, "d", 0),
   (1, "d", 1),
   (2, "d", 4),

   (0, "e", 0),
   (1, "e", 1),
   (2, "e", 4),

   (0, "f", 1),
   (1, "f", 4),
   (2, "f", 7)
];
```

The expected output:

```
Group 1:
a
b
c
f

Group 2:
d
e
```

Why? because functions `a`, `b`, `c`, `f` can be simplified to `3*x+1`
and functions `d`, `e` can be simplified to `x*x`.

Comment: You haven't explained the logic that would *lead* to your desired result. I don't understand your comment in red either - but your example would be better shown as text than as screenshots.

Comment: Additionally, in order for anyone to easily verify the result, it would be helpful for you to include a [mcve]. We shouldn't have to write the code to define the row type and initialize `rows` etc.

Comment: I *suspect* you can just use `foreach (var name in group.Select(row => row.OperatorName).Distinct()) { Console.WriteLine(name); }` but I'm not going to post that as an answer without being able to test it easily...

Comment: You still haven't explained the logic that would lead to your desired results. All you've said is that it should "produce the following output". Heck, we could hard-code that output and it would meet the requirements you've told us about.

Comment: I have a list of logic functions of type `Func<bool?, bool?, bool?>`. For example `var functions = new List<Func<bool?, bool?, bool?>>{(x, y)=>x&y, (x,y)=>(!x&y)|(x&!y)}`.  A truth table can be made from each function and a set of 6 (rather than 9 because of the commutative property) input pairs `(bool? left, bool? right)[] inputs =new[]{(true,null), (true, false), ...};`.

The list `rows` is generated by iterating `functions` and `inputs`. If two functions produces an identical truth table then they are logically equivalent or tautology.

The objective is to group `rows` by tautology.

Comment: My comment saying "your answer is not correct" was directed to another commentator who has deleted his/her comment.

Comment: Everything in your explanatory comment should be in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With a little setup, the actual operations are pretty easy. So, setup first.

For ease of hashing (and performance in general), we can encode your truth tables as simple integers where `true`/`false`/`null` are two bits each, and the operands and results can be concatenated to one integer:

```
record Row(bool? Left, string OperatorName, bool? Right, bool? Result)
{
    public ulong CodedRepresentation =>
        Left switch { true => 1UL, false => 2UL, null => 3UL }
        | (Right switch { true => 1UL, false => 2UL, null => 3UL } << 2)
        | (Result switch { true => 1UL, false => 2UL, null => 3UL } << 4);
}
```

Next we need an enumerable comparer, which is something .Net never provided for some reason:

```
class EnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T>? x, IEnumerable<T>? y) => 
        x is not null && y is not null && !x.Except(y).Any() && !y.Except(x).Any();
    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        var hash = new HashCode();
        foreach (var item in obj.Order())
            hash.Add(item);
        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

And lastly, the actual logic you're looking for:

```
    foreach (var result in rows.GroupBy(r => r.OperatorName)
        .Select(r => (name: r.Key, operations: r.Select(w => w.CodedRepresentation)))
        .GroupBy(w => w.operations, new EnumerableComparer<ulong>()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" = ", result.Select(w => w.name)));
    }
```

All together, the result we get is what you'd expect:

```
and
or
xor = xor_
```

Comment: Your sequence comparer is invalid.  According to it ["a"] and ["a", "b"] are equal.  Also it says that two null sequences aren't equal, which is atypical for most comparers.

Comment: Also there's no real need for your whole coded representation stuff.  Just putting the truth table values into a record/tuple/anonymous type results in a comparer for that data that would work just fine in a properly implemented sequence comparer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could emulate a double grouping based on the current naming conventions. A simple solution would be:

```cs
var q = rows.GroupBy(x => x.OperatorName[..2]);

foreach(var g in q)
{
    var key = g.Select(x => x.OperatorName).Distinct();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", key));
    
    foreach(var r in g.OrderBy(x => x.OperatorName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"  {r}");
    }
}
```

The result would be:

```
and
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = and, Right = , Result =  }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = and, Right = True, Result =  }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = and, Right = False, Result = False }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = and, Right = True, Result = True }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = and, Right = False, Result = False }
  Row { Left = False, OperatorName = and, Right = False, Result = False }
or
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = or, Right = , Result =  }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = or, Right = True, Result = True }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = or, Right = False, Result =  }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = or, Right = True, Result = True }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = or, Right = False, Result = True }
  Row { Left = False, OperatorName = or, Right = False, Result = False }
xor, xor_
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = xor, Right = , Result =  }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = xor, Right = True, Result =  }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = xor, Right = False, Result =  }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = xor, Right = True, Result = False }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = xor, Right = False, Result = True }
  Row { Left = False, OperatorName = xor, Right = False, Result = False }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = xor_, Right = , Result =  }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = xor_, Right = True, Result =  }
  Row { Left = , OperatorName = xor_, Right = False, Result =  }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = xor_, Right = True, Result = False }
  Row { Left = True, OperatorName = xor_, Right = False, Result = True }
  Row { Left = False, OperatorName = xor_, Right = False, Result = False }
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. Try adding some other identical truth tables.

Comment: @user23207089 You asked to group by the `xor` and `xor_` OperatorName. This is exactly what it does.  And now you've modified your question to include additional Operator Names that were not in the original question. This answer is correct based on your original question/sample; you changed the question.